# SolrJ client - Preview request before sending

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj, information-retrieval

Is there a way to view the request the client is about to send to the server? For instance:

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery(query);
solrQuery.setRows(rows);
solrQuery.setIncludeScore(true);

solrQuery.setParam("defType","edismax");
solrQuery.setParam("debugQuery", "true");

// would like to preview the current built up request here
QueryResponse resp = _server.query(solrQuery);
```

Comment: toString should work on SolrQuery. Why logging not tried?

Comment: I wanted something simple, was not sure how to have it log just those requests. Your toString() answer works. If you post as an answer, I will mark it as such. I feel stupid for not trying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SolrQuery.toString](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_7_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/params/ModifiableSolrParams.html#toString%28%29) method gives all the parameters which you can log.